# me sale error al tratar de borrar un dato de mi archivo php con conexion a xampp(MariaDB) no me funciona el delete y sale un error

Tags: php, sql, xampp, mariadb

> > Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clinic`.`consult`, CONSTRAINT `consult_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPat`) REFERENCES `patient` (`idPat`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\Models\patientM.php on line 59
> > este es el codigo del paciente

```
<?php
require_once "Models/vital.php";
if($_SESSION["role"] != "Recepcion" 
&& $_SESSION["role"] != "Doctor" 
&& $_SESSION["role"] != "Administrador" 
&& $_SESSION["role"] != "Patologo"
){
    echo '<script>
    window.location = "inicio";
    </script>';
    return;
}
?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>Gestor de Pacientes</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="content">
        <div class="box">
            
            <div class="box-header">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CrearPaciente">Crear Paciente</button>
            </div>

            <div class="box-body content">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped DT">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>N°</th>
                            <th>Nombre y apellidos</th>
                            <th>tipo doc</th>
                            <th>N° Doc</th>
                            <th>nacionalidad</th>
                            <th>genero</th>
                            <th>fecha de nacimiento</th>
                            <th>edad</th>
                            <th>estado civil</th>
                            <th>direccion</th>
                            <th>N° seguro</th>
                            <th>N° Referencia</th>
                            <th>hora de registro</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        <?php
                            $columna = null;
                            $valor = null;

                            $resultado = PatientC::ViewPatientC($columna, $valor);
                            foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
                            
                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["fullNames"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["typeDoc"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["numDoc"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["nacionality"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["gender"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["birthdate"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["age"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["civilStatus"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["addres"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["idSure"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["numReference"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["regDate"].'</td>
                                    <td>
                                        
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success " Pid="'.$value["idPat"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AñadirExamenFisico"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> ExamenFisico</button>

                                            <button class="btn btn-success EditarPaciente" Pid="'.$value["idPat"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditarPaciente"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar</button>
                                            
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger EliminarPaciente" Pid="'.$value["idPat"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Borrar</button>
                                            
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                    

                                </tr>';

                            }

                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" rol="dialog" id="CrearPaciente">
    
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        
        <div class="modal-content">
            
            <form method="post" role="form">
                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <div class="box-body">
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Nombres y Apellidos:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="fullNames" required>
                            <input type="hidden" name="Pid" value="Paciente">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>tipo de documento:</h2>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="typeDoc" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>numero de Documento:</h2>
                                <input type="int" class="form-control input-lg" name="numDoc" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>nacionalidad:</h2>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nacionality" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>genero:</h2>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="gender" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>fecha de nacimiento:</h2>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="birthdate" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>edad:</h2>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="age" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl- col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-24">  
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2>Estado Civil:</h2>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="civilStatus" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>direccion:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="addres" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>numero de seguro:</h2>
                            <input type="int" class="form-control input-lg" name="idSure" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>numero de referencia:</h2>
                            <input type="int" class="form-control input-lg" name="numReference" required>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

                </div>

                <?php

                $crear = new PatientC();
                $crear -> CreatePatientC();

                ?>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<div class="modal fade" rol="dialog" id="AñadirExamenFisico">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="box-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>paciente:</h2>
                            <?php echo '<select  class="form-control input-lg" name="idPat">
                                <option></option>';
                                $columna = null;
                                $valor = null;
                                $resultado = PatientC::ViewPatientC($columna, $valor);
                                foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$value["idPat"].' "> '.$value["fullNames"].'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>  </select>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Altura:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="height" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Peso:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="sweight" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Temperatura:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="temperature" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Preción:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="price" required>
                        </div>
                        

                    </div>

                </div>

                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submit" name="submit">
                        Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>




<div class="modal fade" rol="dialog" id="EditarPaciente">
    
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        
        <div class="modal-content">
            
            <form method="post" role="form">
                
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <div class="box-body">
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Nombres y Apellidos:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="fullNames" required>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>tipo de documento:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="typeDoc" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>numero de Documento:</h2>
                            <input type="int" class="form-control input-lg" name="numDoc" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>nacionalidad:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nacionality" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>genero:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="gender" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>fecha de nacimiento:</h2>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="birthdate" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>edad:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="age" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>Estado Civil:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="civilStatus" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>direccion:</h2>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="addres" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>numero de seguro:</h2>
                            <input type="int" class="form-control input-lg" name="idSure" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h2>numero de referencia:</h2>
                            <input type="int" class="form-control input-lg" name="numReference" required>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="modal-footer">
                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar Cambios</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

                </div>

                <?php

                $actualizar = new PatientC();
                $actualizar -> UpdatePatientC();

                ?>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<?php

$borrarP = new PatientC();
$borrarP -> DeletePatientC();
```

este es el codigo de la logica

```
<?php

require_once "ConexionBD.php";

class PatientM extends ConexionBD{

    //Crear Pacientes
    static public function CreatePatientM($tablaBD, $datosC){

        $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablaBD(fullNames, typeDoc, numDoc, nacionality, gender, birthdate,age, civilStatus, addres, idSure, numReference)
         VALUES (:fullNames, :typeDoc, :numDoc, :nacionality, :gender, :birthdate ,:age,:civilStatus, :addres, :idSure, :numReference )");
        $pdo2 = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablaBD2(idPat,)
        VALUES (:idPad )");

        $pdo -> bindParam(":fullNames", $datosC["fullNames"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":typeDoc", $datosC["typeDoc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":numDoc", $datosC["numDoc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":nacionality", $datosC["nacionality"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":gender", $datosC["gender"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":birthdate", $datosC["birthdate"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":age", $datosC["age"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":civilStatus", $datosC["civilStatus"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":addres", $datosC["addres"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":idSure", $datosC["idSure"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":numReference", $datosC["numReference"], PDO::PARAM_STR);


        if($pdo -> execute()){
            return true;
        }
        $pdo -> close();
        $pdo = null;

    }

    //Ver Pacientes
    static public function ViewPatientM($tablaBD, $columna, $valor){

        if($columna == null){
            $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaBD ORDER BY fullNames ASC");
            $pdo -> execute();
            return $pdo -> fetchAll();
        }else{
            $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaBD WHERE $columna = :$columna ORDER BY fullNames ASC");
            $pdo -> bindParam(":".$columna, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo -> execute();
            return $pdo -> fetch();
        }

        $pdo -> close();
        $pdo = null;

    }

    //Borrar Paciente
    static public function DeletePatientM($tablaBD, $id){
        $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tablaBD WHERE idPat = :idPat");
        $pdo -> bindParam(":idPat", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($pdo -> execute()){
            return true;
        }
        $pdo -> close();
        $pdo = null;
    }



    //Actualizar Paciente
    static public function UpdatePatientM($tablaBD, $datosC){

        $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("UPDATE $tablaBD SET fullNames = :fullNames, typeDoc = :typeDoc, numDoc = :numDoc, nacionality = :nacionality, gender = :gender, birthdate = :birthdate ,age=:age, civilStatus = :civilStatus, addres = :addres,  idSure = :idSure, numReference = :numReference   WHERE idPat = :idPat");

        $pdo -> bindParam("idPat", $datosC["idPat"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $pdo -> bindParam("fullNames", $datosC["fullNames"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("typeDoc", $datosC["typeDoc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("numDoc", $datosC["numDoc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("nacionality", $datosC["nacionality"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("gender", $datosC["gender"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("birthdate", $datosC["birthdate"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("age", $datosC["age"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("civilStatus", $datosC["civilStatus"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("addres", $datosC["addres"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("idSure", $datosC["idSure"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdo -> bindParam("numReference", $datosC["numReference"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($pdo -> execute()){
            return true;
        }
        $pdo -> close();
        $pdo = null;

    }

//editar pacient
    static public function PatientM($tablaBD, $columna, $valor){

        if($columna != null){
            $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tablaBD WHERE $columna = :$columna");

            $pdo -> bindParam(":".$columna, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo->execute();
            return $pdo -> fetch();
        }
        $pdo -> close();
        $pdo = null;
    }


}
```

> > > en este codigo lo uno

```
<?php

class PatientC{

    public function CreatePatientC(){
        if(isset($_POST["Pid"])){
            $tablaBD = "patient";
            $tablaBD2 = "history";
            $datosC = array("fullNames"=>$_POST["fullNames"],
             "typeDoc"=>$_POST["typeDoc"],
             "numDoc"=>$_POST["numDoc"],
              "nacionality"=>$_POST["nacionality"],
               "gender"=>$_POST["gender"],
                "birthdate"=>$_POST["birthdate"],
                "age"=>$_POST["age"],
                "civilStatus"=>$_POST["civilStatus"],
                "addres"=>$_POST["addres"],
                "idSure"=>$_POST["idSure"],
                "numReference"=>$_POST["numReference"]

            );

            $resultado = PatientM::CreatePatientM($tablaBD, $datosC);

            if($resultado == true){

                echo '<script>
                window.location = "patients";
                </script>';

            }
        }
    }

    //Ver Pacientes
    static public function ViewPatientC($columna, $valor){
        $tablaBD = "patient";

        $resultado = PatientM::ViewPatientM($tablaBD, $columna, $valor);

        return $resultado;
    }



    //Borrar Paciente
    public function DeletePatientC(){

        if(isset($_GET["Pid"])){
            $tablaBD = "patient";
            $id = $_GET["Pid"];
            

            $resultado = PatientM::DeletePatientM($tablaBD, $id);

            if($resultado == true){
                echo '<script>
                window.location = "patients";
                </script>';
            }
        }
    }



    //Actualizar Paciente
    public function UpdatePatientC(){
        if(isset($_POST["Pid"])){

            $tablaBD = "patient";

            $datosC = array("idPat"=>$_POST["Pid"],
             "fullNames"=>$_POST["fullNamesE"],
             "typeDoc"=>$_POST["typeDocE"], 
             "numDoc"=>$_POST["numDocE"], 
             "nacionality"=>$_POST["nacionalityE"], 
             "gender"=>$_POST["genderE"], 
             "birthdate"=>$_POST["birthdateE"],
             "age"=>$_POST["ageE"],
             "civilStatus"=>$_POST["civilStatusE"], 
             "addres"=>$_POST["addresE"],  
             "idSure"=>$_POST["idSureE"], 
             "numReference"=>$_POST["numReferenceE"]);

            $resultado = PatientM::UpdatePatientM($tablaBD, $datosC);
            
            if($resultado == true){

                echo '<script>
                window.location = "patients";
                </script>';

            }
        }
    }

    //editar pat
    static public function PatientC($columna, $valor){
        $tablaBD = "patient";
        $resultado = PatientM::PatientM($tablaBD, $columna, $valor);
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

> > > este es el sql de la base de datos no me deja borrar cuando tengo mas de 2 inserciones a mas de 3 tablas

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

-- Base de datos: `clinic`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `clinicalperson`
--

CREATE TABLE `clinicalperson` (
  `idPerson` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fullNames` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `typeDoc` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numDoc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nacionality` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `birthDate` date NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `civilStaus` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `idSure` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `specialty` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `photo` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `clinicalperson`
--

INSERT INTO `clinicalperson` (`idPerson`, `fullNames`, `typeDoc`, `numDoc`, `nacionality`, `sex`, `birthDate`, `age`, `civilStaus`, `idSure`, `role`, `specialty`, `user`, `pass`, `regDate`, `photo`) VALUES
(1, 'Jose Luis', 'CI', 12434495, 'Boliviana', 'Masculino', '1999-06-02', 0, 'soltero', 0, 'Administrador', 'Administrador', 'admin', '123', '2023-05-14 17:03:44', 'View/img/jose.png'),
(2, 'Jorge Gonsales', 'RUT', 12434412, 'chileno', 'Masculino', '1999-10-03', 0, '1', 12121212, 'Doctor', 'Doctor', 'doctor', '123', '2023-05-14 04:45:26', ''),
(3, 'marcos antonio grajeda colores', 'CI', 12434413, 'bolivia', 'Masculino', '1999-10-04', 0, 'soltero', 12121213, 'emfermera', 'emfermera', 'enfermera', '123', '2023-05-14 04:56:28', ''),
(4, 'Arminda Albarracin Nina', 'CI', 12434433, 'bolivia', 'femenino', '1999-10-05', 0, 'soltera', 12121213, 'recepcionista', 'recepcionista', 'recepcion', '123', '2023-05-14 05:02:59', ''),
(5, 'deysi', 'CI', 124344, 'BOLIVIA', 'fenenina', '1998-05-06', 23, 'soltera', 0, 'Patologo', 'Patologo', 'patologo', '123', '2023-05-31 16:52:33', 'View/img/Doctores/patologo.jpg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `consult`
--

CREATE TABLE `consult` (
  `idCon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `motivo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `padecim` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sustancias` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `idPat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `consult`
--

INSERT INTO `consult` (`idCon`, `motivo`, `padecim`, `sustancias`, `idPat`, `fecha`) VALUES
(8, 'sdfasf', 'fewger', 'asd', 12, '2023-06-29 02:21:55'),
(11, 'mkjl', 'fewger', 'asdfg', 6, '2023-06-29 02:21:55'),
(12, 'mkjl', 'mjk', 'jn', 11, '2023-06-29 13:17:28'),
(13, 'mkjlwfwegeg', 'mjk', 'asd', 9, '2023-07-09 16:05:55'),
(14, 'mkjl', 'mjk', 'asdfg', 7, '2023-07-09 19:29:45');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `history`
--

CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `idHistory` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idVidData` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_medicalOrder` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `history`
--

INSERT INTO `history` (`idHistory`, `idVidData`, `id_medicalOrder`) VALUES
(12, 29, 6);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `medicalorder`
--

CREATE TABLE `medicalorder` (
  `id_medicalOrder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idCon` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `conclucion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tratamiento` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `medicalorder`
--

INSERT INTO `medicalorder` (`id_medicalOrder`, `idCon`, `descripcion`, `conclucion`, `tratamiento`) VALUES
(6, 11, 'sdvsavsv', 'afawfdq', 'asfsgfderbg'),
(7, 12, 'sdvsavsv', 'afawfdq', 'asfsgfderbg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `patient`
--

CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `idPat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fullNames` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `typeDoc` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numDoc` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nacionality` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `civilStatus` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addres` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idSure` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numReference` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `regDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `patient`
--

INSERT INTO `patient` (`idPat`, `fullNames`, `typeDoc`, `numDoc`, `nacionality`, `gender`, `birthdate`, `age`, `civilStatus`, `addres`, `idSure`, `numReference`, `regDate`) VALUES
(6, 'Sara Nicol Vidal Alvarez', 'CI', 98346564, 'BOLIVIA', 'femenina', '1999-05-08', 23, 'soltera', 'zona norte cochabamba', 12434441, 76453241, '2023-05-27 09:37:15'),
(7, 'Jose Luis Choque Ticacolque', 'PASSPORT ', 12434495, 'BOLIVIA', 'masculino', '1999-06-02', 24, 'soltero', 'sacaba', 12434495, 74460900, '2023-05-27 09:39:52'),
(9, 'marco antonio canaviri', 'DNI', 8754234, 'Argentino', 'masculino', '1999-12-01', 24, 'soltero', 'sacaba', 0, 74460911, '2023-06-01 13:54:10'),
(11, 'ROMMEL TELLERIA', 'ci', 123422, 'boliviana', 'MASCULINO', '2023-03-21', 22, 'SOLTERO', 'SACABA', 11123, 4624902, '2023-06-22 13:36:46'),
(12, 'BRYAN ROMMEL TELLERIA ORTEGA', 'CI', 12311, 'boliviana', 'male', '2023-06-30', 46, 'SOLTERO', 'SACABA', 213, 47258834, '2023-06-29 00:09:23');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `typedoc`
--

CREATE TABLE `typedoc` (
  `idTypeDoc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nameDoc` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `abbreviate` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `typedoc`
--

INSERT INTO `typedoc` (`idTypeDoc`, `nameDoc`, `abbreviate`) VALUES
(1, 'CEDULA DE IDENT', ''),
(2, 'PASSPORT ', ''),
(3, 'CEDULA DE IDENT', 'C.I');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `viewconsult`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `viewconsult` (
`idCon` int(11)
,`fullNames` varchar(50)
,`motivo` varchar(50)
,`padecim` varchar(50)
,`sustancias` varchar(50)
,`fecha` timestamp
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `vieworder`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `vieworder` (
`id_medicalOrder` int(11)
,`fullNames` varchar(50)
,`motivo` varchar(50)
,`fecha` timestamp
,`descripcion` varchar(100)
,`conclucion` varchar(100)
,`tratamiento` text
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura Stand-in para la vista `viewvitdata`
-- (Véase abajo para la vista actual)
--
CREATE TABLE `viewvitdata` (
`idVidData` int(11)
,`fullNames` varchar(50)
,`height` varchar(4)
,`sweight` varchar(4)
,`temperature` varchar(4)
,`price` text
);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `vitaledatas`
--

CREATE TABLE `vitaledatas` (
  `idVidData` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idPat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `height` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `sweight` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `vitaledatas`
--

INSERT INTO `vitaledatas` (`idVidData`, `idPat`, `height`, `sweight`, `temperature`, `price`) VALUES
(27, 7, '1.70', '60', '35', '120/90'),
(28, 7, '12.3', '12', '23.4', '120/90'),
(29, 6, '12.9', '12.2', '12.1', '120/90'),
(30, 6, '12.9', '45', '23.4', '120/90');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `viewconsult`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `viewconsult`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `viewconsult`  AS SELECT `consult`.`idCon` AS `idCon`, `patient`.`fullNames` AS `fullNames`, `consult`.`motivo` AS `motivo`, `consult`.`padecim` AS `padecim`, `consult`.`sustancias` AS `sustancias`, `consult`.`fecha` AS `fecha` FROM (`consult` join `patient` on(`consult`.`idPat` = `patient`.`idPat`))  ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `vieworder`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vieworder`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vieworder`  AS SELECT `medicalorder`.`id_medicalOrder` AS `id_medicalOrder`, `viewconsult`.`fullNames` AS `fullNames`, `viewconsult`.`motivo` AS `motivo`, `viewconsult`.`fecha` AS `fecha`, `medicalorder`.`descripcion` AS `descripcion`, `medicalorder`.`conclucion` AS `conclucion`, `medicalorder`.`tratamiento` AS `tratamiento` FROM (`medicalorder` join `viewconsult` on(`medicalorder`.`idCon` = `viewconsult`.`idCon`))  ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura para la vista `viewvitdata`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `viewvitdata`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `viewvitdata`  AS SELECT `vitaledatas`.`idVidData` AS `idVidData`, `patient`.`fullNames` AS `fullNames`, `vitaledatas`.`height` AS `height`, `vitaledatas`.`sweight` AS `sweight`, `vitaledatas`.`temperature` AS `temperature`, `vitaledatas`.`price` AS `price` FROM (`vitaledatas` join `patient` on(`vitaledatas`.`idPat` = `patient`.`idPat`))  ;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `clinicalperson`
--
ALTER TABLE `clinicalperson`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idPerson`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `consult`
--
ALTER TABLE `consult`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idCon`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_vitaledata` (`idPat`),
  ADD KEY `id_vitaledata_2` (`idPat`),
  ADD KEY `idVitData` (`idPat`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `history`
--
ALTER TABLE `history`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idHistory`),
  ADD KEY `idCon` (`id_medicalOrder`),
  ADD KEY `id_medicalOrder` (`id_medicalOrder`),
  ADD KEY `idVitData` (`idVidData`),
  ADD KEY `idVidData` (`idVidData`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `medicalorder`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicalorder`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_medicalOrder`),
  ADD KEY `idCon` (`idCon`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `patient`
--
ALTER TABLE `patient`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idPat`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `typedoc`
--
ALTER TABLE `typedoc`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idTypeDoc`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `vitaledatas`
--
ALTER TABLE `vitaledatas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idVidData`),
  ADD KEY `idPat` (`idPat`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `clinicalperson`
--
ALTER TABLE `clinicalperson`
  MODIFY `idPerson` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `consult`
--
ALTER TABLE `consult`
  MODIFY `idCon` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `history`
--
ALTER TABLE `history`
  MODIFY `idHistory` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `medicalorder`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicalorder`
  MODIFY `id_medicalOrder` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `patient`
--
ALTER TABLE `patient`
  MODIFY `idPat` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `typedoc`
--
ALTER TABLE `typedoc`
  MODIFY `idTypeDoc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `vitaledatas`
--
ALTER TABLE `vitaledatas`
  MODIFY `idVidData` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `consult`
--
ALTER TABLE `consult`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `consult_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPat`) REFERENCES `patient` (`idPat`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `history`
--
ALTER TABLE `history`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `history_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_medicalOrder`) REFERENCES `medicalorder` (`id_medicalOrder`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `history_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`idVidData`) REFERENCES `vitaledatas` (`idVidData`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `medicalorder`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicalorder`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `medicalorder_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCon`) REFERENCES `consult` (`idCon`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `vitaledatas`
--
ALTER TABLE `vitaledatas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `vitaledatas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPat`) REFERENCES `patient` (`idPat`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro. No puedes borrar un paciente que tiene citas en la tabla citas. La integridad referencial la has definido tú mismo en el script y ¡está funcionando!

Comment: El error es claro, pero esta respuesta suele ser bastante relativa y antes de darte una respuesta, que más parecerá un comentario te haré una pregunta. ¿Por qué quieres borrar un paciente?

Comment: Para poder borrar el paciente primero debes borrar la cita, al parecer declaraste claves foraneas/dependencias por lo tanto no podras borrar ciertas cosas que tenga relaciones. @OCHOA no deberias responder esta publicacion, la verdad se cae por su propio peso.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 quizás después de su respuesta fuera aun más conveniente responderla porque recuerde aquella regla no escrita, en una DB nunca se borra nada... Pero bueeee